# List to 2d array in pandas per line NEED MORE EFFICIENT WAY

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe for lists. And each one of the lists can use `np.asarray(list)` to convert the list to a numpy array. The shape of the array should be `(263,300)` ,so i do this

```
a=dataframe.to_numpy()
# a.shape is (100000,)
output_array=np.array([])
for list in a:
    output_array=np.append(output_array,np.asarray(list))
```

Since there are 100000 rows in my pandas, so i expect to get

`output_array.shape is (100000,263,300)`

It works, but it takes long time. 
I want to know which part of my code cost the most and how to solve it.
Is there a more efficient method to reach this? Thanks!

Comment: `np.append()` copies all the data, don't use it in a loop.

Comment: np.append is slow.  Use list append or list comprehension instead

Comment: `np.concatenate(dataframe.to_numpy())` would work assuming many things that aren't clarified in your post.

Comment: so what should i do. use list append to append 100000 lists first, then convert the list to numpy array. sorry i'm fresh

Comment: i do this `lists=[np.asarray(list) for list in a]` , and it is still very slow. Is there a better idea?

Comment: have you tried `pd.a.to_numpy()` ?

Comment: my variable `a` is set to  `a=dataframe.to_numpy()` at first line. and it can only convert to an array of lists, which shape is `(100000,)`, and this is not what i want